# Yoast SEO breadcrumbs missing ListItem name and adding #webpage at the end of the URL

Tags: wordpress, seo, schema, yoast

I am using Yoast SEO.
Our SEO tool is showing an error that we can't seem to fix through the configuration options.

> A value for the name field is required

Apart from the 'missing' name field, Yoast SEO seems to add a #webpage anchor link at the end of the URL. Here is the json-ld output of one of the pages:

```
{
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "@id": "https://testsite.com/international/#breadcrumb",
    "itemListElement": [{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "item": {
            "@type": "WebPage",
            "@id": "https://testsite.com/",
            "url": "https://testsite.com/",
            "name": "Home"
        }
    }, {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "item": {
            "@id": "https://testsite.com/international/#webpage"
        }
    }]
}
```

Is there a way to manually or programmatically add a name to the last ListItem?

And is there a way to remove the #webpage at the end of the URL?

Thanks

Comment: The pattern of id with #webpage is normally used to reference another entity on the page with the same id and more details. e.g. its name. Does your page have another entity with that same id?

Comment: That makes sense. There is a WebPage entity which has the same @id and has the name and other details specified. It makes sense not to duplicate the data in there.

Comment: On our end, it seems to be miss representing that last field too, no matter what content type. According to schema.org the item.name is required. Is this a Yoast bug???

Comment: Test with the Rich Results Tester or the new schema.org validator. They both know how to connect ids and see if the final SD is correct.

Comment: Also having the same issue here - not sure how to solve this one yet...

Comment: Can you test it with the Rich Results Tester or the new schema.org validator. They should populate the item with all the details.